# Null or default comparison of generic argument in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic method defined like this:

```
public void MyMethod<T>(T myArgument)
```

The first thing I want to do is check if the value of myArgument is the default value for that type, something like this:

```
if (myArgument == default(T))
```

But this doesn't compile because I haven't guaranteed that T will implement the == operator.  So I switched the code to this:

```
if (myArgument.Equals(default(T)))
```

Now this compiles, but will fail if myArgument is null, which is part of what I'm testing for.  I can add an explicit null check like this:

```
if (myArgument == null || myArgument.Equals(default(T)))
```

Now this feels redundant to me.  ReSharper is even suggesting that I change the myArgument == null part into myArgument == default(T) which is where I started.  Is there a better way to solve this problem?

I need to support **both** references types and value types.

Comment: C# now supports [Null Conditional Operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx), which is syntatic sugar for the last example you give. Your code would become `if (myArgument?.Equals( default(T) ) != null )`.

Comment: @wizard07KSU That doesn't work for value types, i.e. evaluates to `true` in any case because `Equals` wil always be called for value types since `myArgument` cannot be `null` in this case and the result of `Equals` (a boolean) will never be `null`.

Comment: Equally valuable almost-duplicate (so not voting to close): [Can't operator == be applied to generic types in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/390900/11683)

Answer (score 734, accepted):

To avoid boxing, the best way to compare generics for equality is with `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`. This respects `IEquatable<T>` (without boxing) as well as `object.Equals`, and handles all the `Nullable<T>` "lifted" nuances. Hence:

```
if(EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(obj, default(T))) {
    return obj;
}
```

This will match:

- null for classes
- null (empty) for `Nullable<T>`
- zero/false/etc for other structs

Comment: Wow, how delightfully obscure! This is definitely the way to go though, kudos.

Comment: Definitely the best answer. No squiggly lines in my code after rewriting to use this solution.

Comment: Great answer! Even better is adding an extension method for this line of code so that you can go obj.IsDefaultForType()

Comment: Marc, can you tell me how this is the best way? I mean doesnt `T.Equals` too respect `IEquatable<T>` interface? lets say `Person` class/struct is `IEquatable<Person>`. Now wouldn't calling `p1.Equals(p2)` call the generic version first and if not present then `object.Equals`? Isn't that what `EqualityComparer<Person>.Default.Equals` too does?

Comment: @nawfal in the case of `Person`, `p1.Equals(p2)` would depend on whether it implements `IEquatable<Person>` on the public API, or via explicit implementation - i.e. can the compiler see a public `Equals(Person other)` method. However; in *generics*, the same IL is used for all `T`; a `T1` that happens to implement `IEquatable<T1>` needs to be treated identically to a `T2` that does not - so no, it **will not** spot a `Equals(T1 other)` method, even if it exists at runtime.  In both cases, there is also `null` to think about (either object). So with generics, I would use the code I posted.

Comment: @MarcGravell o yes. Its hard to spot these minor differences when framework gives us 100 ways to do a thing. And mostly the culprit? Non generic .NET 1.1! ;)

Comment: I can't decide if this answer pushed me away from or closer to insanity. +1

Comment: You could also just use the static Object.Equals method.

Comment: @Jordan first three words: "to avoid boxing". `Object.Equals` will cause boxing

Comment: I'm not sure why boxing is a problem here. https://dotnetfiddle.net/ctlPpj

Comment: @Jordan [here's the IL for that](https://gist.github.com/mgravell/7c4134374b73610238b1ea0d300e700b) - as you can see, it clearly boxes. Now, whether boxing is an *issue for you* is contextual. It clearly won't matter for your example since the program exits straight away. However, every box is an allocation. If you deal with anything non-trivial, avoiding *unnecessary* allocations is always to be recommended. These allocations are unnecessary.

Comment: @MarcGravell, only value type and structs are boxed, right? Any time you pass a value type or struct, it allocates a new value type or struct. You aren't using references after all. I can't fathom a way in which comparing two objects of the same type would be harmed by boxing. Doesn't mean there isn't one.

Comment: @Jordan that isn't what boxing means; what you just described is "pass by value", and yes: that happens for structs. But boxing is when you treat a value-type as `object` (or an interface, such as `IEquatable`); this includes passing value-types as parameters of type `object`, which is what `object.Equals` has. When you do this, the value is "boxed" into an object, which means: a new managed-heap object is allocated which encapsulates a copy of the value. When you box two integers: nobody will care. But when this is in a hot-path loop, you can allocate **lots**, **very very quickly** - bad.

Comment: @Jordan the "harm" is simply: by calling `object.Equals(valueX, valueY)`, you have allocated 2 new objects on the managed heap; multiply that by how often you call the method, and you *could* have a very real GC problem

Comment: @MarcGravell, that's fair. I do know what boxing is.

Comment: As a rather related (to the OP's question) side note, I do wonder why `value == default` and `value == default(T)` [behave differently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56602309/11683) in C# 7.1+ in the context of generics.

Comment: @MarcGravell I have used for several years now (thanks BTW), I recently enabled Nullable reference types in my project and know I'm getting a warning that default(T) may be null (CS8604), do you know any other way to check for null, avoid boxing and using generics?.

Comment: @Juan `default(T)!` should tell it to not complain

Comment: @MarcGravell thanks that worked, I was reading this https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30998 and was under the impression that the method will throw if passed null.

Comment: @JuanZamudio, that discussion (30998) seems to say that the implementation doesn't actually throw on null even though it is documented that it could throw on null.

Comment: @rikoe I agree! Why didn't they add something like `public static bool IsDefault<T>(this T value) => EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(value, default(T));
` to the framework?

Comment: Late to this discussion, but as of .NET 6.0, it seems like it is possible to drop the (T), and just write this as EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(value, default) - or at least, my compiler seems to let me.

Answer (score 125):

How about this:

```
if (object.Equals(myArgument, default(T)))
{
    //...
}
```

Using the `static object.Equals()` method avoids the need for you to do the `null` check yourself. Explicitly qualifying the call with `object.` probably isn't necessary depending on your context, but I normally prefix `static` calls with the type name just to make the code more soluble.

Comment: You can even drop the "object." part since it's redundant.

    if (Equals(myArgument, default(T)))

Comment: True, it normally is, but may not be depending on the context. There may be an instance Equals() method that takes two arguments. I tend to explicitly prefix all static calls with the class name, if only to make the code easier to read.

Comment: Need to note that it will cause boxing and in some cases it may be important

Comment: For me this doesn't work when using integers that are already boxed. Because it will then be an object and the default for object is null instead of 0.

Answer (score 34):

I was able to locate a [Microsoft Connect article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto.aspx) that discusses this issue in some detail:

> Unfortunately, this behavior is by design and there is not an easy solution to enable use of with type parameters that may contain value types.
>
> If the types are known to be reference types, the default overload of defined on object tests variables for reference equality, although a type may specify its own custom overload. The compiler determines which overload to use based on the static type of the variable (the determination is not polymorphic). Therefore, if you change your example to constrain the generic type parameter T to a non-sealed reference type (such as Exception), the compiler can determine the specific overload to use and the following code would compile:

```
public class Test<T> where T : Exception
```

> If the types are known to be value types, performs specific value equality tests based on the exact types used. There is no good "default" comparison here since reference comparisons are not meaningful on value types and the compiler cannot know which specific value comparison to emit. The compiler could emit a call to ValueType.Equals(Object) but this method uses reflection and is quite inefficient compared to the specific value comparisons. Therefore, even if you were to specify a value-type constraint on T, there is nothing reasonable for the compiler to generate here:

```
public class Test<T> where T : struct
```

> In the case you presented, where the compiler does not even know whether T is a value or reference type, there is similarly nothing to generate that would be valid for all possible types. A reference comparison would not be valid for value types and some sort of value comparison would be unexpected for reference types that do not overload.

Here is what you can do...

I have validated that both of these methods work for a generic comparison of reference and value types:

```
object.Equals(param, default(T))
```

or

```
EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(param, default(T))
```

To do comparisons with the "==" operator you will need to use one of these methods:

If all cases of T derive from a known base class you can let the compiler know using generic type restrictions.

```
public void MyMethod<T>(T myArgument) where T : MyBase
```

The compiler then recognizes how to perform operations on `MyBase` and will not throw the "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'" error that you are seeing now.

Another option would be to restrict T to any type that implements `IComparable`.

```
public void MyMethod<T>(T myArgument) where T : IComparable
```

And then use the `CompareTo` method defined by the [IComparable interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto.aspx).

Comment: "this behavior is by design and there is not an easy solution to enable use of with type parameters that may contain value types." Actually Microsoft is wrong. There is an easy solution: MS should extend the ceq opcode to function on value types as a bitwise operator. Then they could provide an intrinsic that simply uses this opcode, e.g. object.BitwiseOrReferenceEquals<T>(value, default(T)) that simply uses ceq. For both value and reference types this would check for bitwise equality *of the value* (but for reference types, reference bitwise equality is the same as object.ReferenceEquals)

Comment: I think the Microsoft Connect link you wanted was http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/304501/operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands-of-type-t-and-t

Answer (score 22):

Try this:

```
if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(myArgument, default(T)))
```

that should compile, and do what you want.

Comment: Isn't the <code>default(T)</code> redundant? <code>EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(myArgument)</code> should do the trick.

Comment: 1) did you try it, and 2) what are you then comparing against, the comparer object? The `Equals` method of `IEqualityComparer` takes two arguments, the two objects to compare, so no, it is not redundant.

Comment: This is even better than the accepted answer IMHO because it handles boxing/unboxing and other types. See this "closed as dupe" questions' answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/864860/210780

Answer (score 10):

(Edited)

Marc Gravell has the best answer, but I wanted to post a simple code snippet I worked up to demonstrate it. Run this in a simple C# console app:

```
public static class TypeHelper<T>
{
    public static bool IsDefault(T val)
    {
         return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(obj,default(T));
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // value type
    Console.WriteLine(TypeHelper<int>.IsDefault(1)); //False
    Console.WriteLine(TypeHelper<int>.IsDefault(0)); // True
        
    // reference type
    Console.WriteLine(TypeHelper<string>.IsDefault("test")); //False
    Console.WriteLine(TypeHelper<string>.IsDefault(""));     //False
    Console.WriteLine(TypeHelper<string>.IsDefault(null));   //True 

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

For fun, you can also do it as an extension method:

```
public static class TypeHelper
{
    public static bool IsDefault<T>(this T val)
    {
        return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(val, default(T));
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    // value type
    Console.WriteLine(1.IsDefault());
    Console.WriteLine(0.IsDefault());

    // reference type
    Console.WriteLine("test".IsDefault());
    // null must be cast to a type
    Console.WriteLine(((String)null).IsDefault());
    // Or called with an explicit type argument:
    Console.WriteLine(null.IsDefault<object>());
}
```

Comment: It does "work" as an extension method. Which is interesting since it works even if you say o.IsDefault<object>() when o is null. Scary =)

Answer (score 8):

To handle all types of T, including where T is a primitive type, you'll need to compile in both methods of comparison:

```
    T Get<T>(Func<T> createObject)
    {
        T obj = createObject();
        if (obj == null || obj.Equals(default(T)))
            return obj;

        // .. do a bunch of stuff
        return obj;
    }
```

Comment: Note that the function has been changed to accept Func<T> and return T, which I think was accidentally omitted from the questioner's code.

Comment: Seems ReSharper is messing with me. Didn't realise its warning about a possible comparison between a value type and null was not a compiler warning.

Comment: FYI: If T turns out to be a value type then the comparison against null will be treated as always false by the jitter.

Comment: Makes sense - the runtime will be comparing a pointer to a value type. The Equals() check does work in that case however (interestingly, since it seems very dynamic-language to say 5.Equals(4) which does compile).

Comment: See the EqualityComparer<T> answer for an alternative that doesn't involve boxing et

Answer (score 5):

Extension method based on accepted answer.

```
   public static bool IsDefault<T>(this T inObj)
   {
       return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(inObj, default);
   }
```

Usage:

```
   private bool SomeMethod(){
       var tValue = GetMyObject<MyObjectType>();
       if (tValue == null || tValue.IsDefault()) return false;
   }
```

Alternate with null to simplify:

```
   public static bool IsNullOrDefault<T>(this T inObj)
   {
       if (inObj == null) return true;
       return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(inObj, default);
   }
```

Usage:

```
   private bool SomeMethod(){
       var tValue = GetMyObject<MyObjectType>();
       if (tValue.IsNullOrDefault()) return false;
   }
```

Comment: Ah yes, that weird little detail that you can perfectly call an extension method on a null object without getting a null pointer exception. Honestly, the syntax of calling `obj.ExecuteSomething` on an `obj` that may be null looks really scary.

Comment: Just a small note: no need for null check, Equals does that

Answer (score 4):

There is going to be a problem here -

If you're going to allow this to work for any type, default(T) will always be null for reference types, and 0 (or struct full of 0) for value types.

This is probably not the behavior you're after, though.  If you want this to work in a generic way, you probably need to use reflection to check the type of T, and handle value types different than reference types.

Alternatively, you could put an interface constraint on this, and the interface could provide a way to check against the default of the class/struct.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably need to split this logic into two parts and check for null first.

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(T value)
{
    if (IsNull(value))
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (value is string)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value as string);
    }
    return value.Equals(default(T));
}

public static bool IsNull<T>(T value)
{
    if (value is ValueType)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return null == (object)value;
}
```

In the IsNull method, we're relying on the fact that ValueType objects can't be null by definition so if value happens to be a class which derives from ValueType, we already know it's not null. On the other hand, if it's not a value type then we can just compare value cast to an object against null. We could avoid the check against ValueType by going straight to a cast to object, but that would mean that a value type would get boxed which is something we probably want to avoid since it implies that a new object is created on the heap.

In the IsNullOrEmpty method, we're checking for the special case of a string. For all other types, we're comparing the value (which already know is *not* null) against it's default value which for all reference types is null and for value types is usually some form of zero (if they're integral).

Using these methods, the following code behaves as you might expect:

```
class Program
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public string MyString { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        int  i1 = 1;    Test("i1", i1); // False
        int  i2 = 0;    Test("i2", i2); // True
        int? i3 = 2;    Test("i3", i3); // False
        int? i4 = null; Test("i4", i4); // True

        Console.WriteLine();

        string s1 = "hello";      Test("s1", s1); // False
        string s2 = null;         Test("s2", s2); // True
        string s3 = string.Empty; Test("s3", s3); // True
        string s4 = "";           Test("s4", s4); // True

        Console.WriteLine();

        MyClass mc1 = new MyClass(); Test("mc1", mc1); // False
        MyClass mc2 = null;          Test("mc2", mc2); // True
    }

    public static void Test<T>(string fieldName, T field)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(fieldName + ": " + IsNullOrEmpty(field));
    }

    // public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(T value) ...

    // public static bool IsNull<T>(T value) ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
  private bool IsNull() 
  {
    var nullable = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T)) != null;
    return nullable ? EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(Value, default(T)) : false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a hacky answer and as a reminder for myself.
But I find this quite helpful for my project.
The reason I write it like this is that because I don't want default integer 0 being marked as null if the value is 0

```
private static int o;
public static void Main()
{
    //output: IsNull = False -> IsDefault = True
    Console.WriteLine( "IsNull = " + IsNull( o ) + " -> IsDefault = " + IsDefault(o)); 
}

public static bool IsNull<T>(T paramValue)
{
  if( string.IsNullOrEmpty(paramValue + "" ))
    return true;
  return false;
}

public static bool IsDefault<T>(T val)
{
  return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(val, default(T));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't know if this works with your requirements or not, but you could constrain T to be a Type that implements an interface such as IComparable and then use the ComparesTo() method from that interface (which IIRC supports/handles nulls) like this:

```
public void MyMethod<T>(T myArgument) where T : IComparable
...
if (0 == myArgument.ComparesTo(default(T)))
```

There are probably other interfaces that you could use as well IEquitable, etc.

Comment: OP is worried abt NullReferenceException and you're guaranteeing him the same.

Answer (score -2):

@ilitirit:

```
public class Class<T> where T : IComparable
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public void MyMethod(T val)
    {
        if (Value == val)
            return;
    }
}
```

Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'

I can't think of a way to do this without the explicit null test followed by invoking the Equals method or object.Equals as suggested above.

You can devise a solution using System.Comparison but really that's going to end up with way more lines of code and increase complexity substantially.

Answer (score -3):

I think you were close.

```
if (myArgument.Equals(default(T)))
```

Now this compiles, but will fail if `myArgument` is null, which is part of what I'm testing  for. I can add an explicit null check like this:

You just need to reverse the object on which the equals is being called for an elegant null-safe approach.

```
default(T).Equals(myArgument);
```

Comment: I was thinking the exact same thing.

Comment: default(T) of a reference type is null and results in a guaranteed NullReferenceException.