# Test for equality to the default value

Tags: c#, generics, equality

The following doesn't compile:

```
public void MyMethod<T>(T value)
{
    if (value == default(T))
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

**Error: `Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'`**

I can't use `value == null` because `T` may be a struct.
I can't use `value.Equals(default(T))` because `value` may be `null`.
**What is the proper way to test for equality to the default value?**

Comment: replied to comment; and for info, `EqualityComparer<T>` is the standard implementation used by the BCL, for example in `Dictionary<,>`.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65351/null-or-default-comparsion-of-generic-argument-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 118, accepted):

To avoid boxing for `struct` / `Nullable<T>`, I would use:

```
if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(value,default(T)))
{
    // do stuff
}
```

This supports any `T` that implement `IEquatable<T>`, using `object.Equals` as a backup, and handles `null` etc (and lifted operators for `Nullable<T>`) automatically.

There is also `Comparer<T>.Default` which handles comparison tests. This handles `T` that implement `IComparable<T>`, falling back to `IComparable` - again handling `null` and lifted operators.

Comment: Are you saying that `EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals` has better performance than `Object.Equals`, or that it would give a correct value in some case that `Object.Equals` wouldn't?

Comment: Better performance (less boxing); consider `T=int`; to call `object.Equals` it has to box `value` and `default(T)` - that's two extra heap allocations + GC. Using `EqualityComparer<T>` it has 3 different underlying implementations - `class`, `Nullable<T>` and `struct` - it can then do everything (including `null` tests) without **any** boxing. The work of figuring out which implementation to use is only done once per type and cached, so still very fast.

Comment: @MarcGravell I can't seem to get this to work.  I created a function with this inside to try and determine if the structure is still the default value.  It seems to always return `FALSE` (not default value).  Did I do something wrong?  Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35897019/checking-a-structures-default-value

Answer (score 40):

What about

```
object.Equals(value, default(T))
```

Comment: I knew it should be simple. Thank you.

Comment: +1. Tested. Works correctly with various types: `MyMethod(0); MyMethod<String>(null); MyMethod<DataSet>(null);` - in each case returns true.

Comment: The downside with this is that it will unnecessarily box value types (which is why `EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals` is preferred)