# Checking a structure's default value

Tags: c#, generics, struct, .net-4.0

There is something wrong in my DefaultValue() function.  It ALWAYS returns `false`, representing that the the structure is NOT the default value.

Why would this not work?

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct ArrayItem
{
    public long SrcSize;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 250)]
    public string SrcFile;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 250)]
    public string DestFile;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
private struct MyInfo
{
    public int Count;

    public int AppOne;

    public int AppTwo;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 100, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.Struct)]
    public ArrayItem[] Files;
}


private bool DefaultValue<T>(T structure)
{
    if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(structure, default(T)))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

//Success returns 'Value Changed' as expected
MyInfo fileInfoOne = new MyInfo();
fileInfoOne.Count = 3;
fileInfoOne.Files = new ArrayItem[100];
fileInfoOne.Files[0].SrcSize = 100;
Debug.Write("fileInfoOne: ");
if (DefaultValue(fileInfoOne.Files[0])) Debug.WriteLine("Default Value."); else Debug.WriteLine("Value Changed.");


//Fails but has all the default settings, should return 'Default Value'
MyInfo fileInfoTwo = new MyInfo();
fileInfoTwo.Files = new ArrayItem[100];
fileInfoTwo.Files[0].SrcSize = 0;
fileInfoTwo.Files[0].SrcFile = "";
fileInfoTwo.Files[0].DestFile = "";
Debug.Write("fileInfoTwo: ");
if (DefaultValue(fileInfoTwo.Files[0])) Debug.WriteLine("Default Value."); else Debug.WriteLine("Value Changed.");
```

Comment: First off, the posted code always throws NRE. Second, `fileInfoTwo` is not used.

Comment: @IvanStoev thanks for that, +1 for the help.  I got it corrected and after trying it out myself to make sure it compiled and ran ok I noticed it was working!  My IRL application is still returning false every time.  I think it has to do with the fact that I'm setting the array object.  Even though I'm setting it with default values the structure itself is maybe not the default?

Comment: The default values are 0 (zero) for value types and `null` for reference types. If you are testing `MyInfo` struct with array set, it will never be default (array is a reference type).

Comment: Thanks for that, but nah I'm just testing the ArrayItem object.  I was thinking about doing some type of reflective approach to it.  Like maybe compare all the properties in `<T>`.

Comment: @IvanStoev Turns out my issue was with how the array items were getting defined!  You pointed out `The default values are 0 (zero) for value types and null for reference types.`  That got me to try setting the value types (strings) to null instead of "".  Add an answer to that effect for the points!  ;)  Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome, glad that helped a little. Probably it doesn't deserve to be an answer, but since you kindly proposed, I will post it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No worry, your `DefaultValue()` function is just fine :)

But when you calling it, make sure you don't initialize the test `struct` members with empty array/string objects. `default` means `0`(zero) for value types and `null` for reference types. NET Framework `Array`s and `String`s are reference types, so if they are not `null`, the function will report them as non default.

Answer (score 0):

In the hopes this might help someone else out too...  I have come up with a work around for my situation.  In my case (dealing with memory mapping) I pass a null value into a memory map and that null value eventually gets read as a blank string ("").  Because of this I ended up coming up with this function to check (account) for blank strings.  This only works for me because I know that if my string are blank they are invalid anyway so they might as well be null).

```
private bool NoFile<T>(T structure)
{
    bool valueIsDefault = true;

    foreach (FieldInfo f in typeof(T).GetFields())
    {
        object defaultVal = f.GetValue(default(T));
        object structVal = f.GetValue(structure);
        if (structVal.GetType() == typeof(string) && (string)structVal == "") structVal = null;

        if (!object.Equals(structVal, defaultVal))
        {
            valueIsDefault = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return valueIsDefault;
}
```