# Does a generic function implicitly cast value types to objects when checking for null?

Tags: c#, reference, null, value-type

For example the following code demonstrates my line of thought:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int i = 0;
        IsNull(i);  // Works fine

        string s = null;
        IsNull(s);  // Blows up
    }

    static void IsNull<T>(T obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException();
    }

}
```

Also the following code:

```
int i = 0;
bool b = i == null;  // Always false
```

Is there an implicit object cast going on? such that:

```
int i = 0;
bool b = (object)i == null;
```

Comment: FYI, you should never throw `NullReferenceException`. I also disagree with your naming of `IsNull`. It should be something like `ThrowIfNull`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `obj` gets boxed by the compiler. This is the IL generated for your `IsNull` function:

```
.maxstack 8

IL_0000: ldarg.0
IL_0001: box !!T
IL_0006: brtrue.s IL_000e

IL_0008: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.NullReferenceException::.ctor()
IL_000d: throw

IL_000e: ret
```

The `box` instruction is where the casting happens.

The compiler doesn't know anything specific about `T` so it must assume that it must be an `object` - the base type of everything in .NET; this is why it boxes `obj` to make sure that the null check can be performed. If you use a [type constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) you can give more information to the compiler about `T`.

For example, if you use `where T : struct` your `IsNull` function won't compile anymore because the compiler knows `T` is a value type and null is not a value for value types.

Boxing a value type instance always returns a valid (non-null) object instance*, so the `IsNull` function would never throw for a value type. This is actually correct behavior if you think about it: the numeric value `0` is not `null` - a value type value cannot possibly be `null`.

In the code above `brtrue.s` is very much like `if(objref!=0)` - it doesn't check the value of the object (the value type value before boxing) because at the time of the check, it's not a value that's on top of the stack: it's the boxed object instance that's on top. Since that value (it's really a pointer) is non-null, the check for `null` never comes back as true.

*Jon Hanna pointed out in a comment that this statement is not true for `default(Nullable<T>)` which is correct - boxing this value returns `null` for any `T`.

Comment: Oh, I would expect that to be optimized.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I guess the compiler has no idea what the type of `T` is so it has to box the value to ensure that the null check can be performed. Using a type constraint for `T` would solve it but then the code wouldn't compile since `null` is not a valid value for value types.

Comment: Does this mean if you use the == operator on generics that the base object equals will be called? i.e. obj == null becomes => ((object)obj).equals(null), making the method signatureL bool Equals(object, object). So you can very easily get the wrong equals method if you compare two <T>'s that have overridden the Equals method? Such that the base.Equals is called, not the strongly typed bool Equals(T a, T b)???

Comment: @user1515024 If you look at the above code, `Equals` is not called for the null check - the compiler simply calls `brtrue.s` to see if the value is non-null or not. For the non-null case, it just returns, otherwise it falls through to the exception.

Comment: @user1515024 In the more generic case where you'd call `Equals()` with some value, the function that gets called would probably be the `Equals()` overload on base type of `T`. In your case, that'd be `object` but you can use a type constraint to make your `T` more specific.

Comment: @xxbbcc OK, that IL means nothing to me, might as well be Klingon. Surely the equals method that overrides the == operator is invoked by the brtrue.s command through?

Comment: @user1515024 No, `brtrue.s` is very much like `if(objref!=0)`. It's not _exactly_ that, but it's not a function call, just a straight check. `IL_000e` after the instruction is just the target offset where the instruction jumps if the condition is true.

Comment: @xxbbcc You mean like checking if a pointer has an address or if it points to a special null value?

Comment: @user1515024 I edited the answer, please see that - let me know if it's unclear to you, I'll try to add more detail.

Comment: "Boxing a value type instance always returns a valid (non-null) object instance". Not true, box `default(Nullable<T>)` for any `T`, and you get null.

Comment: @JonHanna You're right - I'll update the answer for that. I didn't think of this one.

Comment: This answer is incorrect -- yes, the IL has a box instruction, but the IL code is also generic.  The JIT compiler does optimize away the box.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Your expectation is correct; the JIT compiler does optimize out the null check for value types.

Comment: @user1515024 actually, you can't use `==` on a value of an unconstrained generic type parameter.  Try it; you'll get a compiler error.

Answer (score 7):

xxbbcc's answer assumes that the OP is asking "why isn't 0 equal to null", which may well be what the question is all about.  On the other hand, in the context of generic types, questions about boxing often have to do with the performance benefit that generic types offer by avoiding boxing.

In considering that question, the IL could be misleading.  It includes a box instruction, but that doesn't mean that a boxed instance of the value type will actually be allocated on the heap.  The IL "boxes" the value because the IL code is also also generic; the substitution of type arguments for type parameters is the responsibility of the JIT compiler.  For a non-nullable value type, the JIT compiler optimizes away the IL instructions for boxing and checking the result because it knows that the result will always be non-null.

I added a Thread.Sleep call to the sample code, to give time to attach the debugger.  (If you start the debugger in Visual Studio with F5, certain optimizations are disabled even if it is a release build).  Here's the machine code in Release build:

```
            Thread.Sleep(20000);
00000000 55                   push        ebp 
00000001 8B EC                mov         ebp,esp 
00000003 83 EC 0C             sub         esp,0Ch 
00000006 89 4D FC             mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],ecx 
00000009 83 3D 04 0B 4E 00 00 cmp         dword ptr ds:[004E0B04h],0 
00000010 74 05                je          00000017 
00000012 E8 AD 4B 6A 71       call        716A4BC4 
00000017 33 D2                xor         edx,edx 
00000019 89 55 F4             mov         dword ptr [ebp-0Ch],edx 
0000001c 33 D2                xor         edx,edx 
0000001e 89 55 F8             mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],edx 
00000021 B9 C8 00 00 00       mov         ecx,0C8h 
00000026 E8 45 0E 63 70       call        70630E70 

            int i = 0;
0000002b 33 D2                xor         edx,edx 
0000002d 89 55 F8             mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],edx 
            IsNull(i);  // Works fine
00000030 8B 4D F8             mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-8] 
00000033 FF 15 E4 1B 4E 00    call        dword ptr ds:[004E1BE4h] 

            string s = null;
00000039 33 D2                xor         edx,edx 
0000003b 89 55 F4             mov         dword ptr [ebp-0Ch],edx 
            IsNull(s);  // Blows up
0000003e 8B 4D F4             mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-0Ch] 
00000041 BA 50 1C 4E 00       mov         edx,4E1C50h 
00000046 FF 15 24 1C 4E 00    call        dword ptr ds:[004E1C24h] 
        }
0000004c 90                   nop 
0000004d 8B E5                mov         esp,ebp 
0000004f 5D                   pop         ebp 
00000050 C3                   ret
```

Note that the call instruction has a different target for the int and the string.  Here they are:

```
            if (obj == null)
00000000 55                   push        ebp 
00000001 8B EC                mov         ebp,esp 
00000003 83 EC 0C             sub         esp,0Ch 
00000006 33 C0                xor         eax,eax 
00000008 89 45 F8             mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],eax 
0000000b 89 45 F4             mov         dword ptr [ebp-0Ch],eax 
0000000e 89 4D FC             mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],ecx 
00000011 83 3D 04 0B 32 00 00 cmp         dword ptr ds:[00320B04h],0 
00000018 74 05                je          0000001F 
0000001a E8 ED 49 6E 71       call        716E4A0C 
0000001f B9 70 C7 A4 70       mov         ecx,70A4C770h 
00000024 E8 2F FA E9 FF       call        FFE9FA58 
00000029 89 45 F8             mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],eax 
0000002c 8B 45 F8             mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-8] 
0000002f 8B 55 FC             mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-4] 
00000032 89 50 04             mov         dword ptr [eax+4],edx 
00000035 8B 45 F8             mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-8] 
00000038 85 C0                test        eax,eax 
0000003a 75 1D                jne         00000059 
                throw new NullReferenceException();
0000003c B9 98 33 A4 70       mov         ecx,70A43398h 
00000041 E8 12 FA E9 FF       call        FFE9FA58 
00000046 89 45 F4             mov         dword ptr [ebp-0Ch],eax 
00000049 8B 4D F4             mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-0Ch] 
0000004c E8 DF 22 65 70       call        70652330 
00000051 8B 4D F4             mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-0Ch] 
00000054 E8 BF 2A 57 71       call        71572B18 
        }
00000059 90                   nop 
0000005a 8B E5                mov         esp,ebp 
0000005c 5D                   pop         ebp 
0000005d C3                   ret
```

and

```
            if (obj == null)
00000000 55                   push        ebp 
00000001 8B EC                mov         ebp,esp 
00000003 83 EC 0C             sub         esp,0Ch 
00000006 33 C0                xor         eax,eax 
00000008 89 45 F8             mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],eax 
0000000b 89 45 F4             mov         dword ptr [ebp-0Ch],eax 
0000000e 89 4D FC             mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],ecx 
00000011 83 3D 04 0B 32 00 00 cmp         dword ptr ds:[00320B04h],0 
00000018 74 05                je          0000001F 
0000001a E8 ED 49 6E 71       call        716E4A0C 
0000001f B9 70 C7 A4 70       mov         ecx,70A4C770h 
00000024 E8 2F FA E9 FF       call        FFE9FA58 
00000029 89 45 F8             mov         dword ptr [ebp-8],eax 
0000002c 8B 45 F8             mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-8] 
0000002f 8B 55 FC             mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-4] 
00000032 89 50 04             mov         dword ptr [eax+4],edx 
00000035 8B 45 F8             mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-8] 
00000038 85 C0                test        eax,eax 
0000003a 75 1D                jne         00000059 
                throw new NullReferenceException();
0000003c B9 98 33 A4 70       mov         ecx,70A43398h 
00000041 E8 12 FA E9 FF       call        FFE9FA58 
00000046 89 45 F4             mov         dword ptr [ebp-0Ch],eax 
00000049 8B 4D F4             mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-0Ch] 
0000004c E8 DF 22 65 70       call        70652330 
00000051 8B 4D F4             mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-0Ch] 
00000054 E8 BF 2A 57 71       call        71572B18 
        }
00000059 90                   nop 
0000005a 8B E5                mov         esp,ebp 
0000005c 5D                   pop         ebp 
0000005d C3                   ret
```

Looks more or less the same, right?  But here's what you get if you start the process first and then attach the debugger:

```
            Thread.Sleep(20000);
00000000 55                   push        ebp 
00000001 8B EC                mov         ebp,esp 
00000003 50                   push        eax 
00000004 B9 20 4E 00 00       mov         ecx,4E20h 
00000009 E8 6A 0C 67 71       call        71670C78 
            IsNull(s);  // Blows up
0000000e B9 98 33 A4 70       mov         ecx,70A43398h 
00000013 E8 6C 20 F9 FF       call        FFF92084 
00000018 89 45 FC             mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],eax 
0000001b 8B C8                mov         ecx,eax 
0000001d E8 66 49 6C 70       call        706C4988 
00000022 8B 4D FC             mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-4] 
00000025 E8 46 51 5E 71       call        715E5170 
0000002a CC                   int         3
```

Not only has the optimizer removed the boxing of the value type, it has inlined the call to the IsNull method for the value type by removing it altogether.  It's not obvious from the above machine code, but the call to IsNull for the reference type is also inlined.  The `call 706C4988` instruction seems to be the NullReferenceException constructor, and `call 715E5170` seems to be the `throw`.

Comment: I'm not sure why you call my answer incorrect. The question was _Is there an implicit object cast going on?_ to which the answer is obviously true - the `box` instruction is proof of that. In x86 assembly there's no concept of types so obviously there's no "casting" logic there. Eliminating an object instance is an optimization of the implementation of `box`. Your answer is correct but it's not an answer to the question.

Comment: @xxbbcc I took "implicitly cast to object" to mean "physically put a copy of the value on the heap at run time." That's what people are usually concerned about when they discuss boxing, and it is one of the main reasons for the .NET implementation of generic types. In that context, my answer is correct and yours is not. If the question is about the logic of the C# and CLR type systems, purely abstractly, then your answer is correct and mine misses the point. Perhaps user1515024 can tell us which context was intended.

Comment: Well, the language of the source is C# and the language rules pretty much require a boxing operation to happen. Do you think it's wise for people to rely on the underlying optimizing JIT-ter eliminating the boxed object instance in this particular case? I mean, based on your argument, `null` and `0` are one and the same since the JIT-ter removed all code that would say otherwise.

Comment: Wise?  I don't know.  But given that null checks are sometimes needed in code that can't be constrained to a reference type (which I suppose is why they are allowed), people should know that such checks are not going to incur a performance penalty for value types.  How else would you protect against a null reference exception in `T Min<T>(T x, T y) where T : IComparable<T> { return y == null ? x == null ? 0 : 1 : y.CompareTo(x) < 0 ? y : x; }`?

Comment: Or consider IDictionary, which does not allow null keys.  If the null check incurred a boxing penalty for value-type keys, it would rather defeat the purpose of the type.

Comment: Except the question has nothing to do with performance. The question is about the result of `(int) 0 == null`. In the context of C# this can only be explained through boxing. What you're talking about is an assembly-level optimization of two physical `0` values, since there's no such thing as `null` in assembly.

Comment: First, assemblies are IL, where null is meaningful.  Second, the optimization of the expression has nothing to do with zero.  The result would be the same if it were `(int)42 == null`.  And the JIT optimization actually relies on the knowledge that the result of boxing a non-nullable value type will always be a *non*-zero object reference.  The C# equivalent would be replacing (0 == null) with false.  I also disagree with your assumption that the question has nothing to do with performance.  I suspect that, implicitly, it does.

Comment: Absolutely not! The OP posted the question because he expected `IsNull(0)` to fail. He wouldn't have posted for `IsNull(42)` because it'd be `false`, in line with his expectation. So the question is about logic flow (will the true branch of the `if` execute for a certain value of a certain `T`). I don't see any relevance of the performance argument here since the optimization happens in a different language and on a different platform (managed CLR vs unmanaged x86 assembly).

Comment: I also think you misunderstood the point of my answer - the IL code is not the explanation, it's just demonstration of the compiler's lack of sufficient knowledge about `T`. How else would you explain `(int)x==null`? There's no guarantee that other implementations of the CLR would perform the same optimizations but the C# language rules would still be the same for those implementations.

Comment: I did not understand from the question that the OP expected (0 == null) to be `true` (nowhere is that actually stated explicitly).  If that's the case, then yes, I completely misunderstood the question (which is why I also misunderstood your answer).  I will rewrite the first sentence of my answer.

Comment: You could be right about the OP's intent. What makes me think that he's expected `IsNull(0)` to fail are the comments in his code (`Works fine` and `Blows up`). To me these indicate that he expected a single "consistent" behavior.

Comment: I think you're right.  I took the comments as simply illustrating the code's behavior, but there's not much reason to illustrate that behavior unless it's unexpected.  Plus, it never occurred to me that anyone could expect 9 to equal null -- it's been several years since I've worked in a language where they are equal.

Comment: I think your answers are both correct, but leave some stuff out (what the other answer has, and some more stuff that I added my own answer to fill in). IME, when people are asking about comparisons between null and a value that may or may not be non-nullable, what they want to know is if they're paying a performance penalty for cruft, which is what this answer here deals with, and so it's the one I would consider the best (my own is just filling in gaps), but the consideration of C# as IL production tool in the first answer is vitally important for a full understanding, too.

Comment: +1 for the low-level detailed analysis of the code's behavior.

Answer (score 3):

There's a value to both of the two answers here, and I would give the mark to phoog as answering the practical concern most people have when they ask about this (variants of it have come up before). But there is also an incompleteness.

There are four ways of looking at the code in question, and all four are important, and the answers have only looked at two (though phoog's entailed a lot about one other).

I'll start with the part of the question that was ignored so far:

> Also the following code:

```
int i = 0;`
bool b = i == null;  // Always false`
```

> Is there an implicit object cast going on? such that:

```
int i = 0;
bool b = (object)i == null;
```

Well, yes and no. It depends on the level we are looking at it, and we actually have to look at it at different levels at different times, so saying so is not mere pedantry.

C# is four things:

1. It is a computer language in its own right. We can reason in it and about it and examine whether or not something follows its rules, and what it means according to those rules.
2. It is a way of producing CIL, which is another language in its own right, to which the above apply.
3. Via CIL, it is a way of producing machine code, either at runtime or through Ngen, which is also a language in its own right.
4. It is a way of telling a computer to do something, which is usually the main point of the exercise.

So far answers have looked at point 2 and 3, but the full picture looks at all four.

And the most important points are actually point 1 and 4.

Point 1 is important because C# is after all the language we are looking at, and the view colleagues are most likely to look at. Since programming is partly instructing a computer to do something, and partly expressing one's intent as one did so (medium- and high-level programming languages are for people first, computers second), the actual source code is important.

Point 4 is important because that is after all our final goal. It is not the same thing as looking at the assembly of the machine code (as phoog's answer did) because machine code is not the final answer as to what changes and optimisations are done:

1. CPUs do optimisations of their own. This is particularly relevant when branching comes up.
2. Two pieces of assembly that when considered purely as a theoretical language are equivalent may differ in how well they treat CPU caches.
3. Two pieces of assembly that when considered purely as a theoretical language are equivalent may differ in that one performs unaligned reads that cause performance problems, incorrect results, exceptions or screens-of-death.
4. Two pieces of assembly that when considered purely as a theoretical language are equivalent my differ in performance because one uses an instruction that the CPU happens to perform faster than the other's logically-equivalent instruction.
5. And so on...

Now, all that said, in the cases we're looking at now, the machine code is about as far as we need to look to reason about the machine's behaviour. In general though, machine code is not the final answer every time. Still, phoog's answer isn't a fault for implying rather than stating the impact here; I only mention it because I'm aiming to write about the different conceptual levels at which both phoog and xxbbcc are correct in different ways.

Coming back to our code of `bool b = i == null` where `i` is of type `int`.

In C# `null` is defined as a literal value that is the default for all reference types, and for nullable value types. It can be compared with any value for reference equality - that is, the question "Are X and Y the same instance" can be asked with `null` as the value for X and the answer is true if Y is not an instance, and false otherwise.

To make this comparison with a value type, we must box the value type, just as we must any of those cases where we need to treat a value type as a reference type.

If the value type is a nullable value type, and it is null (`HasValue` returns false), then boxing produces a null reference. In all other cases boxing a value type creates a reference to a new object on the heap, of type `object` which refers to the same value and can be unboxed back to it.

Therefore the answer at the conceptual level of C# is "yes, i is implicitly boxed to create a new object that is then compared to null [which hence will always return false]".

At the next level, we have CIL.

In CIL, null is a value with a natural word-size (32-bit in a 32-bit process, 64-bit in a 64-bit process) bit pattern of all-zero (hence `brfalse`, `brzero` and `brnull` all just being aliases for the same bytecode) which is a valid value for managed pointers, pointers, natural integers and any other means to give an address).

Also in CIL, boxing is done to an equivalent boxed type; it's not just `object`, but `boxed type of int`, `boxed type of float`, etc. This is hidden from C# because it's not very useful (you can't do anything with these types other than those things you can do on `object` and unbox back to the equivalent unboxed type), but is more precisely defined in CIL because it needs to do the implementation of "how can boxing be done on lots of different types?".

The equivalent code in CIL would at a minimum be:

```
ldc.i4.0                   // push the value 0 onto the stack.
box [mscorlib]System.Int32 // pop the top value from the stack, box it as boxed Int32,
                           // and push that boxed value onto the stack.
ldnull                     // push null (all zeros) onto the stack
ceq                        // pop the top two values onto the stack, if they are equal
                           // push 1 onto the stack, otherwise push 0 onto the stack.
//Instructions that actually act on "b" here, probably a stloc so it can be loaded as needed later.
```

I say "at a minimum" as there might be some loading from and storing to the locals array for the method in question.

So, at the CIL level the answer is also "yes, i is implicitly boxed to create a new object that is then compared to null [which hence will always return false]".

However, this is not actually the CIL that would be produced. In a release build it would be:

```
ldc.i4.0                   // push the value 0 onto the stack.
//Instructions that actually act on "b" here, probably a stloc so it can be loaded as needed later.
```

That is, it will optimise the code that always produces false to code that just produces false. Even in a debug build we would likely have some optimisation.

But I wasn't lying when I said that in CIL the code for comparing an integer with null involves boxing; it does, but the C# compiler can see that this code is a waste of time, and just replaces it with code that loads false into `b`. Indeed, if `b` isn't used later on, it might just cut out the whole thing. (Conversely, if `i` is used later on, it will still load `0` into it at some point, rather than cut it out as in the example above).

This is the first time we've come up against compiler optimisation here, and it's time to examine just what that means.

Compiler optimisation comes down to a simple observation; if a piece of code can be rewritten as a different piece of code that has the same effects as seen from the outside, but is faster and/or uses less memory and/or results in a smaller executable, then only a moron will complain if you produced the faster/smaller/lighter version instead.

This simple observation becomes complicated by two things. The first is what to do when given the choice between a faster version and a lighter version. Some compilers give options for weighing these choices (most C++ compilers do), but C# does not. The other is what does "as seen from the outside" mean? It used to be simple "any output produced, interactions with other processes, or operations on volatile* variables". It gets a bit more complicated when you have multiple threads, one of which is performing garbage collection, all of which are of course "outside" of each other, in that this makes the number of cases where an optimisation (esp. if it involves reordering) could affect what is observed. Still, none of that applies here.

The C# compiler does not do a lot of optimisation, since the jitter is going to do a lot anyway, so the downside of optimisation (1. all work is a chance for a bug so if you don't do a particular optimisation you won't have a bug related to that optimisation. 2. the more you optimise something the more you can confuse the developer looking at it) becomes more significant if a given optimisation would be done by the next layer anyway.

Still, it does do **that** optimisation.

Indeed, it will optimise away whole sections. Take the code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  int i = 0;
  if(i == null)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("wow");
    Console.WriteLine("didn't expect that");
  }
  else
  {
    Console.WriteLine("ok");
    Console.WriteLine("expected");
  }
}
```

Compile it, then decompile it back into C# and you get:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Console.WriteLine("ok");
  Console.WriteLine("expected");
}
```

Because the compiler can remove entire sections of code it knows will never be hit.

So, while in both C# and IL, comparing a value type to null involves boxing, the C# compiler will remove such pointless cruft and no boxing will actually happen. It will also issue warning CS0472, because if you put obviously pointless cruft in your code something was likely wrong with your thinking, and you should look at it and figure out what you really meant to do.

It's worth at this point also looking at what would happen if `i` was of type `int?`; which can be boxed to a null. There is still an optimisation made:

1. Most of the time the boxing and comparison gets replaced by a call to the `HasValue` field. This is more efficient than boxing.
2. Sometimes the compiler can (due to knowledge of the value in question) optimise even that away.

(The matter of assembly is irrelevant at this stage, since the boxing and comparison has already been removed).

Now, if we have the case of a generic method (or method of a generic class) that accepts both value and reference type parameters, this optimisation cannot be done by the C# compiler, because generic methods aren't instantiated into their particular specialised form at compile time (unlike the otherwise similar C++ templates), but at jitting time.

For this reason, the IL produced will always include the boxing operation (unless there was another reason why it could be optimised away even in the case of reference types).

The jitter though, has much the same knowledge of the fact that boxing a non-nullable value type will never produce a null value, that the C# compiler did with our first example. It is also much more aggressive in optimisation than the C# compiler ever is.

This is where we get the behaviour that phoog described in their answer: In the code produced for a value-type type parameter, the boxing operation is completely removed (with a reference-type parameter the boxing operation is essentially a no-op and also removed). The check is removed, as the answer is known, and indeed entire sections of code that would be executed only if that check had returned true, are also removed.

The case phoog didn't examine is that of a nullable value type. Here, at a very minimum the boxing and comparison will be replaced with a call to `HasValue`, which in turn will be inlined to a read of the internal field in the struct. Possibly (if it's known that the value is never null, or if it's known that it's always null) that will be removed, along with one whole section of code that would never be executed anyway.

**Summary**

There are two more specific questions behind your question, and you may be interested in one or both of them.

Question 1: I am interested in how C# functions as a language, and I want to know if as far as C# is concerned, comparing a non-nullable value-type with null boxes that value type.

Answer 1: Yes, a comparison with null can only be done with a reference type - including a boxed value type - and so there is always a boxing operation.

Question 2: I have generic code which compares a value with null, because I want to do something only if it's a reference type or nullable value type, *and* if the value is equal to null. Will my code pay the performance penalty of a boxing operation in the cases where the type compared is a value type?

Answer 2: No. In those cases where the C# compiler cannot optimise away the code from the IL it produces, the jitter still can. For non-nullable value types the entire boxing operation, comparison, and code-path only taken when the comparison with null returned true, will all be removed from the machine code produced, and thus from the work the computer does. Furthermore, if it's a nullable value type, the boxing and comparison will be replaced with an examination of the field in the value that indicates whether `HasValue` is true or not.

*Note that this definition of `volatile` is related to, but not the same as, that in .NET, for reasons that are also related to how greater support for multi-threaded execution has complicated things from how they were in the 1960s.

Comment: +1 for the detailed analysis of the various scenarios. Do note, however, that the IL in my answer is from a release build with all optimizations on. The C# compiler simply cannot optimize away the `box` from the output because it doesn't know what `T` will be (since it doesn't generate all specializations of a generic function).

Comment: @xxbbcc Indeed, that's what I'm covering from "Now, if we have the case of a generic method…" on, the IL can't optimise it away, as it's not yet something that won't have an effect (as per your answer), but the jitter can (as per phoog's answer). An understanding of both is important, as indeed is the level above the IL and the level below the machine code; hence my saying that both your and phoog's answer are correct.

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right. I read through your answer but I must've skipped that paragraph.

Comment: @xxbbcc the problem with writing long answers but relatively quickly (rather than the write, leave, return, re-draft of a more thorough essay) is that it's easy to have a flow that fails to make sure all important bits stand out, so the flaw is quite likely mine.

Comment: +1 for the 4 ways of looking at C#, a nice way to frame the discussion.  If you look at the history of nullable value types, though (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2005/08/11/450640.aspx for example) you will find that the use of properties to determine their nullness is not an optimization that makes it unnecessary to box the value; rather, the boxing behavior reconciles the frustration that would result if `((object)(int?)null)` yielded a (non-null) boxed instance of `int?`, as it did in the first implementation.

Comment: Also there is something you can do with a `boxed instance of type int` (for example) that you can't do with an object in C#, which is to use it as an `instance of IComparable<int>` (for example).

Comment: 2 comments ago, I should have pointed out (with reference to "Most of the time the boxing and comparison gets replaced by a call to the HasValue field") that actually, the C# spec calls for `x == null` and `x != null` to be compiled as calls to the HasValue method, so it's not an optimization, it's the definition of the language.  That's why I didn't discuss nullable value types in my answer.

Comment: If I had had more time, I would have called the method to see how it behaved when invoked with a nullable value type.  It seems like it *couldn't* use HasValue, so I suppose it would have to rely on the special boxing behavior of nullable value types (unless the jitter knows about the HasValue property, of course).