# Does Performing a Null Check on a Generic Cause Boxing?

Tags: c#, .net, boxing

I looked around for this and could not find an answer.  Say I have this code:

```
class Command<T> : ICommand<T>
{
    public void Execute(T parameter)
    {
        var isNull = parameter == null;
        // ...
    }
}
```

`T` could be any class, even a `Nullable<>`.  Does performing the check above cause boxing if `T` is a value type?  My understanding is that this is the same as calling `ReferenceEquals` which takes two `object` arguments, either of which would cause boxing if `T` was a value type, if I understand correctly.

If the above does cause boxing, is there a more preferred way to do this without causing the box to occur?  I know there is `default(T)` but in the case of `int` that is `0`, and I am looking to see if this value is `null` without boxing it.  Also, I am looking to do this in a way that satisfies both value and reference types.

Comment: Related: [Why can I test a generic for null when it may not be nullable or may not be an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080598/why-can-i-test-a-generic-for-null-when-it-may-not-be-nullable-or-may-not-be-an-o), especially E.Lippert's answer [Why can I test a generic for null when it its runtime type might be neither a nullable value type nor a reference type?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5080924/284240)

Comment: And: [Does a generic function implicitly cast value types to objects when checking for null?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21343471/397817)

Comment: By the way, you can simplify your question to: why is this allowed: `bool intIsNull = 1 == null`, which is also perfectly legal (but useless) code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No - at least not in my understanding. If `T` is a non-nullable value type, the `parameter == null` check is effectively replaced with `false` by the JIT compiler; no execution-time check is performed.

This is an optimization that only the JIT-compiler can perform, as the C# compiler only generates one form of code. For example, the IL generated for your sample is:

```
IL_0000:  ldarg.1
IL_0001:  box        !T
IL_0006:  ldnull
IL_0007:  ceq
```

That would appear to actually perform the boxing - but I trust a decent JIT compiler to spot that when `T` is non-nullable, the `ceq` will always give a false result, and remove the box operation.

Comment: Awesome.  An answer from the venerable Mr. Skeet.  Cross that off the tech bucket list. :)  Thank you for taking the time to answer!