# default(T) behaviour on anonymous types

Tags: c#, unit-testing, generics

I'm in the process of writing unit tests against our core framework, and came across this.

We have an extension method that looks like this:

```
    public static T ThrowIfDefault<T>(this T self, string variableName)
    {
        if (self.Equals(default(T)))
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("'{0}' cannot be default(T)", variableName));
        return self;
    }   // eo ThrowIfDefault<T>
```

(A variation on a `ThrowIfNull<>` extension method I saw here on Stack Overflow.

In writing a test case for this, I first wrote a helper:

```
    public void ThrowIfDefaultTestHelper<T>(T value)
    {
        // unit test *itself* requires that a value be specified!!
        Assert.AreNotEqual(default(T), value);

        // Good test
        GenericExtensionMethods.ThrowIfDefault(value, "value");

        // Bad test
        try
        {
            GenericExtensionMethods.ThrowIfDefault(default(T), "value");
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            // Expected result
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

And then the following:

```
    [TestMethod()]
    public void ThrowIfDefaultTest()
    {
        ThrowIfDefaultTestHelper<int>(10);
        ThrowIfDefaultTestHelper<Guid>(Guid.NewGuid());
        ThrowIfDefaultTestHelper<DateTime>(DateTime.Now);
        ThrowIfDefaultTestHelper<object>(new { Name = "Test" });    // anonymous object
    }
```

The Unit test fails on the last one as a `NullReferenceException` is thrown, because I am guessing `object` has no `default(T)` (or does it?).  Can I not test anonymous objects this way?

Comment: It's kind of strange to use an instance method (`Equals`) in a method whose only purpose is to check for `null`...

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, absolutely!  It's the little things that people miss that when others look at, it's utterly obvious.  Hence, very good idea to use unit tests... we're all human :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`object` does have `default(T)`, it just happens to be `null`. This is unlike your other test cases that use non-nullable value types. That's why you get a `NullReferenceException` instead of the one that you expect.

If you replace

```
self.Equals(default(T))
```

with

```
EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(obj, default(T))
```

you should start getting the expected `ArgumentException`.

Comment: *slaps forehead*  That makes perfect sense.  Thank you.

Comment: Furthermore, this is a perfect example of why unit-testing is important on apparent "that'll always work" code :)

Comment: One last point, just for clarity - I do pass `string` in there which is not a value type, and the test passes fine.  I am assuming therefore `default(T)` for string is non-null?

Comment: @Moo-Juice: In the code you provided, you don't pass `default(T)` with `T == typeof(string)`. If you would do that, you would get the `NullReferenceException` just as you do for every other reference type. `default(string)` is `null`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth, good point - so it's safe to say it would have died there instead of the last one.  My bad.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Moo-Juice One more thing, the code that I wrote for comparing with `null` is not as good when you use value types. I edited the answer with a portion of Marc's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/864860/335858) that I used throughout my code.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, thanks!  I have updated my function, and as expected - the unit test passes with flying colours and dancing girls.