# How to handle default values for null variables?

Tags: javascript, c#

In javascript I can do this

```
var value = obj.A || 3;
```

which means, if `obj.A` is null or undefined or empty, then use 3 instead.

How can I do that in c#? Or is this the best way in c#?

```
int value = obj.A == null ? 3 : obj.A;
```

Comment: Use the [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator): `??`.  However this only works on null values not "empty" or other "default" values, _only null_

Comment: In other words int value = obj.A?? 3

Comment: `int value = obj == null ? 3 : obj.A`

Comment: @Devid that is the same code OP posted though?

Comment: @Devid that doesn't solve the main issue, which is straight from the OP: if `*obj.A* is null or undefined or empty, then use 3 instead`.

Comment: In my opinion OP has already figured out the most similar way to do it in C#.

Comment: There is no native `truthy` check in c# like there is in javascript. You would have to build your own or add an additional check against the default value. `int value = (obj.A == null  || obj.A == default(int)) ? 3 : obj.A;`

Comment: @Devid Thats a pretty false statement though.  The most "similar" way is to use a null coalescing operator (assuming a check for null).  If OP wants to check against arbitrary "falsey" values like Javascript, then _there is no built in way_ in C#

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using null propagation `?.` and the null coalescing operator `??`.

```
var value = obj?.A ?? 3;
```

The first one says "if obj is null, ignore A and just use null". The second one says "if the left-hand side is null, use the right hand side"

Comment: I just noticed I answered the wrong question. This works if obj OR A are null. It won't check if A has never been defined. C# doesn't have the same concept of 'undefined' as JavaScript and will default int properties to 0

Comment: But it would work if `.A` was of type `int?`, which is the closest C# can come

Comment: Instead of `var` i suggest to use the real type `int` for clarity

Comment: This doesn't check for empty though. So if obj.A is 0 (for int) or empty string ("" for string) then that will be set instead of 3.

Answer (score 0):

> ... if obj.A is null or undefined or empty, then use 3 instead.

c# has no concept of `undefined`. There is not much you can do about this, if you want an equivalent you would have to create some sort of generic type wrapper but I would advise against it.

There is also no native `truthy` check (which is what you are actually referring to when you wrote "empty") in c# like there is in javascript. You would have to build your own method or extension method or add an additional check against the default value in comparison that you want to do.

```
class Temp
{
    public int? A {get;set;}
}

public static void Main()
{
    Temp obj = new Temp();

    int resultingValue1 = (obj.A == null  || obj.A == default(int)) ? 3 : (int) obj.A;
    // or
    int resultingValue2 = obj.A.IsNullEmpty() ? 3 : (int) obj.A;
}
```

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsNullEmpty<T>(this T valueToCheck) 
    {
        return valueToCheck == null || EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(valueToCheck, default(T));
    }
}
```

See also Marc Gravell's answer [Null or default comparison of generic argument in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/864860/1260204)

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IOGyDz)